# Troubleshooting latency spikes

Tags: networking, troubleshooting

I have a friends laptop here which she asked me to take a look at. The trouble is that she constantly has trouble with her internet connection - cable not connecting trough LAN interface and wi-fi has poor connectivity. Tried it on a set of different networks and routers (which I use everyday and have no problem) - it's the same. The funny things is, if the laptop is hooked to the wi-fi that comes from the router, that I am hooked to via cable, I start getting latency spikes too.

I am almost certain this is malware or driver trouble, but I need to be certain. Any ideas on reliable way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: `if the laptop is hooked to the same wi-fi that I am hooked to via cable` - That statement makes no sense. Are you connected wirelessly or wired?

Comment: the same router - I am with cable